# How to fix "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

So I wrote this function and for the life of me cannot work out what is wrong with it. It is an extremely basic function yet when I try and compile it I get

```
    LoopArraysLibrary.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
            for (var i=0, x=0, y=1, x1=0;i<5;i++)
                 ^
      symbol:   class var
      location: class LoopArraysLibrary
    1 error
```

This is the function:

```
public static int fib(int n) {
    for (var i=0, x=0, y=1, x1=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    return(x);
    x1=x;
    x=y;
    y=x1+y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing Java with JavaScript, not the same language.

Comment: sorry...removed java tag

Comment: @user2998265 If it's javascript, then why is it in a .java file?

Comment: I am really confused, sorry. It is a java file

Comment: Sorry, but this question is messed up. What is `var`? The question suggests that you're just guessing at stuff. I strongly urge you to at least read a book or two or tutorial since guessing and making stuff up won't work.

Comment: @user2998265 Then if you're writing java, the simple answer is that `var` is not a java type. If you're trying to write javascript, the issue then is that except for `var`, everything else seems to be java syntax.

Comment: its a java program and I am getting the error that they cannot find the symbol for the class var. I made a mistake between javascript and java

Comment: thank you dennis that is what I needed. How do I upvote you?

Comment: Upvoting the comment is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no keyword or built-in type name `var` in Java.  (Java is NOT Javascript!!)

It looks like those variables need to be `int`, so you could declare the variables like this:

```
    for (int i=0, x=0, y=1, x1=0;i<5;i++)
        { ...
```

However, that's not enough because the first statement in the loop body is

```
           return(x);
```

and that is going to cause the Java compiler to say that the statements after are unreachable code.  Based on what you are trying to implement, your code should be returning *after the loop*.  And that means that `x`, `y` and `x1` should not be declared as local to the loop.

I'll leave you to work out how to implement that ... and find / fix the other problem :-)

---

**UPDATE**: Starting with Java 10 (release March 2018) the language supports `var` for local variables.